# Ubuntu pinging from link-local address instead of global

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing, ipv6

I have a network like this, (client 2001:10:1:100:0/64) -> router -> (server 2001:172:16:200:0/64)

However, when I ping from client to the 172.16.200.0 network, (or anywhere) it always uses the link local address instead of the global.

```
ens192    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e8:87:5a
      inet addr:10.1.100.11  Bcast:10.1.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee8:875a/64 Scope:Link <------ uses this
      inet6 addr: 2001:10:1:100::11/64 Scope:Global <----- want to use this
```

I can see this on my router debug, note the source address is the link local, not the global

```
FGT-B (vd1) # id=20085 trace_id=5 func=resolve_ip6_tuple_fast line=4005 msg="vd-vd1:0 received a packet(proto=58, fe80::20c:29ff:fee8:875a:1115->2001:172:16:200::44:128) from port2."
id=20085 trace_id=5 func=resolve_ip6_tuple line=4122 msg="allocate a new session-00000163"
id=20085 trace_id=5 func=vf_ip6_route_input line=1117 msg="find a route: gw-2001:172:16:200::44 via port3 err 0 flags 01000001"
id=20085 trace_id=5 func=ip6_forward line=547 msg="invalid source address, drop"
```

The error I get on client is this

```
root@user1-virtual-machine:~# ping6 2001:172:16:200::44
PING 2001:172:16:200::44(2001:172:16:200::44) 56 data bytes
From fe80::926c:acff:fefb:b53b icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fe80::926c:acff:fefb:b53b icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Routing table

```
2001:10:1:100::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens160  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via 2001:10:1:100::2 dev ens192  metric 1024  pref medium
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with the router, not the endpoints.

Comment: Probably because you're using teredo tunneling addresses for your IPv6? It's also not clear if you're trying to get your router to do 6to4 translation for you which is done on the 2002::/16 block and ipv4 mapped addresses on the ::ffff:0:0/96 block.

Comment: Just a guess but try: `ping6 ::ffff:0:172:16:200:0`

Comment: Please show us your routing table: `ip -6 r`.

Comment: @johan, i attached my routing table

Comment: That doesn't look like the routing table for your router. Again, you need to be looking at your router, not your computer(s).